# Simulating multiple low bandwidth network interfaces on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, emulation

I'm making a testbed for a Linux based application that uses multiple GPRS connections and aggregates their bandwidth.

I'd like to test this application on my local ethernet by emulating low bandwidth high latency network conditions on multiple network interfaces.

To achieve this, I tried setting up multiple Virtual NICs using macvlans on single ethernet and then I tried traffic shaping using wondershaper and netem on each interface. However, for some reason, traffic is not being shaped on Macvlans.

Could there be a better solution for emulating multiple cellular interfaces using single ethernet card?

Comment: have you tried tc command? http://lartc.org/howto/